# Does exist an holomorphic function $f$ on $|z|>1$, non-constant, and bounded by the limit at $\infty$?

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

I have a question in my book that asks to show that if a function $f$ is holomorphic on $\{z:|z|>1\}$, continuous on $\{z: |z|=1\}$and has limit on $\infty$ then its maximum is for some point $w$ with $|w| = 1$. I have solved the problem except for one case in which the function is bounded by its limit at $\infty$. So, that is my question, is that possible? Can the maximum be at $\infty$ instead of the unit circle? I have come across with [another similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195276/bounded-holomorphic-function-on-an-unbounded-region) but with no response. I have tried using Liouville's theorem but the function isn't even defined in the whole plane. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is holomorphic in $\{z:|z|>1\}$, continuous on $\{z: |z|=1\}$and has limit at $z =\infty$, then it is bounded by its values on $|z|=1$, i.e.
$$
 \max \{ |f(z) | : |z| > 1 \} = \max \{ |f(z) | : |z| = 1 \} \, .
$$

For a proof consider $g(z) =f(1/z)$, which is holomorphic in $\{z: 0 < |z|<1\}$, continuous on $\{z: |z|=1\}$and has a limit at $z=0$.

Now apply [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann%27s_theorem) to conclude that $g$ can be extended to a holomorphic function on the entire unit disk. The maximum modulus principle then shows that $g$ is bounded by its values on $|z|=1$, so that the same is true for $f$.

In addition, if $f$ is bounded by its value at $\infty$ then $g$ is bounded by $|g(0)|$, which implies that $g$ (and consequently $f$) is constant.

Comment: I believe you don't need Riemann's theorem, the function is continuous on the unit disk. And the maximum modulus principle is true with those two hypothesis. Apart from that is fine.

Comment: @JosePérezCano: In order to conclude that the maximum is attained on the boundary of the unit disk you need a function which is holomorphic inside the unit disk, including the origin. That's where Riemann's theorem is used.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but I don't call it on removable singularities. I call it Riemann extension theorem. That's why I thought you were refering to something else.

Comment: @JosePérezCano: Perhaps there are different names, I know it as “Riemann's theorem on removable singularities” (link added to answer). Also I prefer to distinguish between "has a limit at $z=0$” and “is continuous at $z=0$”.